# awk: fatal: cannot open file 'file' for reading (Permission denied)

Tags: python, awk

A piece code below is part of a larger program which I am running on a remote server via a batch script with `#!/bin/bash -l` as its first line.

On my local machine it runs normally but on a remote server permission issues arises. What may be wrong?

The description of the code may not important to the problem, but basically the code uses awk in processing the contents of the files based on the names of the files.

Why is awk denied permission to operate on the files? When I run awk directly on a shell prompt of the remote server it works normally.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list_of_files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

for file in list_of_files:
       awk_cmd = '''awk '/^>/{print ">" substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)) ++i; next} 1' ''' + file +  " > tmp && mv tmp " + file + \
                 " | cat files > 'pooled_file' "
       exitcode = subprocess.call(awk_cmd, shell=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's being run in the wrong directory. Try and specify the location

Comment: When you're running it in terminal, it's probably a different user or *sudo* user - make sure your file has proper permissions and ownership, proper access rights given to your *awk*. - you can try  `chmod +x your_location`

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is a permissions issue since when you are landing into remote machine it is NOT landing on directory where your Input_file(s) are present, off course it will land in HOME directory of logged in user at remote server. So it is a good practice to mention file names with complete paths(Make sure file names with path you are giving are present in target location too else you could write a wrapper over it to check either files are present or not too). Could you please try following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list_of_files = ["/full/path/file1", "/full/path/file2", "/full/path/file3"]

for file in list_of_files:
       awk_cmd = '''awk '/^>/{num=split(FILENAME,array,"/");print ">" substr(array[num],1,length(array[num])) ++i; next} 1' ''' + file +  " > tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ " + file + \
                 " | cat files > 'pooled_file' "
       exitcode = subprocess.call(awk_cmd, shell=True)
```

I haven't tested it but I have changed it as per full path, since `awk` will print complete path with filename so I have changed `FILENAME` in your code to as per array's place, I also changed `tmp` temporary file to `tmp$$` for safer side.

Comment: Thanks but it still returns awk: fatal: cannot open file `/absolute/path/of/the/file' for reading (Permission denied) error; even when the absolute file path is specified

Comment: @user3014974, ok, could you please check 2 things, first either those files are present in that path or not, second permissions are there or not edit permissions lemme know then.

Comment: The files that I am passing awk on are automatically generated by another script as part of the pipeline and these are the type of permissions I have as a user -rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 6695428 Oct 9 17:02 file. Awk can operate on this file if I pass directly on the prompt, but not via subprocess.call.

Comment: @user3014974, Try to give an execute permission too, to all once?